# TFS Error While Associating Check-in with a Task

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I use TFS Eclipse plug-in to manage Java source code and I'm facing a problem every time I try to check-in a file.

We have a policy that every check must be associated with a task now every time I try to associate a change set with a task and then check-in I get the following error:[image]

Comment: What version of Team Explorer Everywhere are you using?  What version of the server is this?  And what version of your IDE are you running?

Comment: we use TEE 2010, TFS 2010 and Eclipse 10.0 blue. and we sync TFS with Microsoft Project Server 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a TFS server that has Project Server Integration installed, you will need to use [Team Explorer Everywhere 10.0 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25125) (or newer.)

Comment: first thanks for your response. I do update to TEE SP1 but still we face the same problem

Comment: It looks like I was supposed to clear the TFS cache after I've installed the TEE SP1